# Tkinter Canvas creating rectangle

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

In python, tkinter, I'm trying to make a game that involves creating shapes onto a canvas. For example, I want a red rectangle to appear over my canvas image. When I execute my code, the rectangle you see is about 1 pixel in size, and I'm not sure why and how it got like that. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x900")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=550, height=820)
canvas.pack()
png = PhotoImage(file = r'example.png') # Just an example
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = png, anchor = "nw")

a = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 0, 50, 0, fill='red')
canvas.move(a, 20, 20)
```

Hope this can be resolved.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `create_rectangle` method takes 4 coordinates:
`canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, **kwargs)`, with (x1,y1) the coordinates of the top left corner and (x2, y2) those of the bottom right corner. But you gave twice the same coordinates so your rectangle has a zero width and height, that's why you can only see a pixel. Try with `canvas.create_rectangle(50, 0, 100, 50, fill='red')` and this time you should get a square of side 50 pixels.

You can get more details about the arguments of `create_rectangle` on this [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20181223164027/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html).

Comment: is (x2, y2) exclusive?

Comment: @Hzzkygcs What do you mean by that? Also, you can probably answer your own question by trying out the code.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you want to create a rectangle with dynamic size then you can do

```
canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill='red')
```

This will create a rectangle with your specified `width` and `height`.